# Move divs outside of container while keeping the same background

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, css-position

I need to move three thumbnails outside of the main container but maintain the same background-image as their container.

Here is a picture of [what i need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixsTM.png).

I'm using bootstrap, so the thumbnails are inside a row. I got to move the thumbnails using the class .move-tb in the row

```
.move-tb{
    position: relative;
    bottom: -120px;
}
```

but the problem comes with the background.

I guess i should use a common background-image in a main div, and then separate two divs, first one with all the content and `background-color: transparent` and second one just to set its `background-color: gray`, but then when i move the thumbnails, how do i get them to use the main-background (image) instead of the second inner-div background (gray color)??

Comment: Keep your single div ( rectangular ) having background and place div's with white color with absolute position at bottom side as given in image.

Comment: @NitinDhomse It will overlap the columns right? I think It may not work.

Comment: @Ajithkumar Yes, it works. need to use css with position : absolute and other supporting css properties like left / right.

Comment: @NitinDhomse let me try your answer..

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is draw bottom white part from Adobe Illustrator and save it as a SVG. Then open svg file from a text editor and copy  tag to your html..then you can style and arrange as you want.